# Count row number based on a value of other column

Tags: mysql

I've a MySQL table like that

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | ref_by |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | SM   |        |
+----+------+--------+
| 2  | MO   | 1      |
+----+------+--------+
| 3  | Go   | 2      |
+----+------+--------+
| 4  | ZZ   | 1      |
+----+------+--------+
```

It is a user table where the "ref_by" column holds the id of the user by whom the user is referred.

I want to select the top 10 user who have top referral.
I did that on PHP by searching the user id and counting the referred user. That is too much time consuming.

What will be an efficient query that will produce a result like this:

```
name ref_count
SM   2
MO   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using a self-join here:

```
SELECT
    t1.name,
    COUNT(t2.id) AS ref_count
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id = t2.ref_by
GROUP BY
    t1.name
ORDER BY
    ref_count DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: If you don't want to see names which had a zero referral count, then add the following `HAVING` clause to the above query:

```
HAVING ref_count > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. I've to wait 6 min to accept the answer.

Comment: But it takes a long time.

Comment: There isn't much that can be done to speed up this query AFAIK, because every record needs to be counted.